# Beamer ignoring a \label when used inside certain \only's

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

For space reasons I want to break up the contents of an `itemize` list into separate slides, which I have been doing without much problem using `\only`.  However, the following minimal document complains that the label `eq:formula` is not defined:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
 \begin{itemize}
 \only<1>{
  \item Item 1.
 }             % Comment 
 \only<2>{     % these lines
  \item Item 2, with equation
  \begin{equation}
   \label{eq:formula}
   xyz
  \end{equation}

  \item Item 3, with reference \eqref{eq:formula}.
 }
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it is clearly defined.  The problem goes away if you comment out the marked lines (thus, printing everything on one slide).  I see using `\tracingmacros` that there is a serious redefinition of `\label` in beamer, and as such it appears that this is a bug with detecting what slide the label is printed on.

Is that right, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s `\label` is also overlay-aware. Following `\show\label` (*outside* the `frame` environment), you'll notice

```
> \label=macro:
->\@ifnextchar <{\beamer@label }{\beamer@label <1>}
```

which implies `\label{<stuff>}` *without* an overlay specification defaults to `\label<1>{\stuff>}` making it only label on slide 1 by default. This, of course, motivates why having only a single slide makes the references work as expected. Consequently, use `\label<2>{eq:formula}` for the label to be active on slide 2.

Here's the complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
 \begin{itemize}
 \only<1>{%
  \item Item 1.
 }
 \only<2>{%
  \item Item 2, with equation
  \begin{equation}
   \label<2>{eq:formula}
   xyz
  \end{equation}

  \item Item 3, with reference \eqref{eq:formula}.
 }
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

True, it would be nice if `\label` was self-sufficiently slide-aware...

Comment: I see, not a bug but a feature :)