# Equation labels not resolved within a beamer overlay (simple list environment)

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, overlays

Putting an equation \label{} within a list \item, **where the item is to be revealed selectively as an overlay**, seems to result in LaTeX hiding the reference from itself. Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\fontsize{6pt}{7.2}\selectfont
Outside of the \texttt{list} environment (with overlays), there is no
  problem resolving equation number references, e.g.
\texttt{\textbackslash ref\{eq:eq1\}} resolves to eq \ref{eq:eq1}:
\begin{equation}
    x=1
\label{eq:eq1}
\end{equation}
However within a simple list, where an \texttt{\textbackslash item} appears
within an overlay: equation reference labels are not accessible (even
within the overlay itself). See below:
\begin{list}{}{}
\only<1>{\item Item 1: Not very interesting.}
\only<2>{\item Item 2:
\begin{equation}
    x=2
\label{eq:eq2}
\end{equation}
The reference \texttt{\textbackslash ref\{eq:eq2\}} appears unresolved as
eq \ref{eq:eq2}, although eq \ref{eq:eq1} (outside the list) is still
resolved OK.}
\end{list}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Pasting the above code and running pdflatex on it, I get the output as attached:
[image: Output of above MWE]

Rerunning latex numerous times fails to resolve the missing reference: the log file contains:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )pdfTeX warning (dest): name{eq:eq2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Can anymore give me a pointer has to how to reveal these references?

Comment: Not addressing your problem, but: Does it make sense to cross-reference in a presentation? The audience will hardly remember the numbers and the associated equations.

Comment: These are not just live presentations, but lengthy published notes, so yes, accurate cross-referencing of equations and citations, etc., is critical for them to have any lasting value.

Comment: Add `<2>` after `\label`. See also [Beamer ignoring a \label when used inside certain \only's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/beamer-ignoring-a-label-when-used-inside-certain-onlys).

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

1. As already said by `@gernot` use `\label<2>{eq:eq2}`
2. Any special reason you are using `list` in the first place? Beamer has good support for `itemize` environments, even if you don't want the itemize symbols, you could do:

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{equation}
    x=1
\label{eq:eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item[] Item 1: Not very interesting.
    \item[] Item 2:
            \begin{equation}
                x=2
            \label{eq:eq2}
            \end{equation}
            \ref{eq:eq2} \ref{eq:eq1}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```