# pager reference issue when using only in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I use beamer and and once in a while I reference with `\pageref{label}` some previous slides. 
Somewhere along my presentation I included a frame with 5 `\only` statements - like this

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \label{frame:foo}
    \begin{figure}
        \only<1>{
            \includegraphics[width=.91\textwidth]{./center0.pdf}}
        \only<2>{
            \includegraphics[width=.91\textwidth]{./center1.pdf}}
        \only<3>{
            \includegraphics[width=.91\textwidth]{./center2.pdf}}
        \only<4>{
            \includegraphics[width=.91\textwidth]{./center3.pdf}}
        \only<5>{
            \includegraphics[width=.91\textwidth]{./center4.pdf}}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

As expected, this creates five slides with the same page number, that is, my page counter now looks like 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7... If I now reference to page 7 the pageref in the compiled beamer document says "on page 11" instead of "on page 7" as it refers to the actual pages in the document.

How can I make `\pageref{}` report the counter on the slide and not the actual number of slides where I am referencing to?

Comment: Did you have a look at this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/beamer-ignoring-a-label-when-used-inside-certain-onlys?rq=1

Comment: Hadn't seen it. Funny, I never had issues with referencing my formulas. The pagref would point to the wrong slide but the \ref{equation} get's the right one.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=foo]
        \frametitle{title}
    \begin{figure}
        \only<1>{1}
        \only<2>{2}
        \only<3>{3}
        \only<4>{4}
        \only<5>{5}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
 As seen in frame \ref{foo}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, this is more intricate than I thought. The solution is not the \begin{frame}[label=foo] but it is the different behavior of \ref{} vs. \pageref{}. If you were to use \pageref{foo} in your solution, the page number in the compiled document would still point to the wrong slide. \ref{} in turn, gets the right slide, no matter how you label your frame. I.e, you can also label somewhere with \labe{foo} within the body.  However, the problem persists with \pagelabel{equation:foo}. As \ref{} returns the equation number and \pageref{equation:foo} should return the actual slide - which it desn't.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `\setcounter` and it fixed the issue. That is, after the slide/frame with the `\only`-statement write

```
\setcounter{page}{6}
```

and the pageref's will be pointing to the right pages again.

**Edit**

Given samcarters's comment one could also use `\ref{}` to obtain the correct frame page number. However, if the slide is addressed by `\pageref{}` it will point to the actual slide number and not to the page number on that slide - which does not need to be the same.

Hence, if one wants to address the slide page number via a equation label, the `\ref{equation:label}` would return the equation number and using `\pageref{equation:label}` would return the "wrong" slide page number. In this case it's probably best to either fix the setcounter or to simply add another label for that frame which is then addressed by `\ref{}`.

Short, don't use `\pageref{}`, use `\ref{}` instead