# Redefining \label to not default to <1>

Tags: beamer, macros, cross-referencing, labels

According to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/beamer-ignoring-a-label-when-used-inside-certain-onlys), labels are defined by default on a beamer slide to always be defined at the first slide `<1>`. Indeed `\show\label` shows

```
> \label=macro:
->\@ifnextchar <{\beamer@label }{\beamer@label <1>}
```

A solution is to use `\label<2>` for example to define labels on the second slide. I would rather not change all my labels. Instead, is there a way to redefine label so that it does *not* default to slide `<1>`, using the current slides like other commands?

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer} \begin{document} \show\label \end{document}`, shows the macro definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\label` in order to change `<1>` to `<+->` (current and following). However, this only works for regular labels and not for display labels (such as in an equation), because `beamer` redefines these at the start of a math environment. For such cases you can use a custom macro like `\mathlabel`. This is not so convenient as just using `\label`, but it is easier than having to figure out which number you should put.

MWE, adapted from the referenced question:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\label{\@ifnextchar <{\beamer@label }{\beamer@label <+->}}
\def\mathlabel{\@ifnextchar <{\beamer@label@in@display }{\beamer@label@in@display <+->}}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}{Title}
 \begin{itemize}
 \only<1>{
  \item Item 1.
 }             
 \only<2>{     
  \item Item 2, with equation
  \begin{equation}
   \mathlabel{eq:formula}
   xyz
  \end{equation}
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{abc}
  \label{fig:empty}
  \end{figure}

  \item Item 3, with references \eqref{eq:formula} and Figure \ref{fig:empty}.
 }
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]