# Cannot reference to figure in overprint of beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I have some figures that should take turn showing up below itemized text. The problem is referencing to these figures later on becomes impossible no matter how many recompilation. How should i correct it?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item ABC
        \item XYZ
        \item DEF
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering
                \caption{ABC}
                \label{fig:ABC}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ABC}
            \end{figure}
        \onslide<2>
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering
                \caption{XYZ}
                \label{fig:XYZ}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{XYZ}
            \end{figure}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome back to TeX.SE! Are you sure you want to refer to figures in your presentation? If the figure is on another slide when you refer to it then it is not clear what the reference refers to, and when it is on the same slide you can just write "look at this figure" (or say it out loud and point to it with the mouse or a laser pointer).

Comment: But considering the question itself: probably a duplicate of [Beamer ignoring a \label when used inside certain \only's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44595/beamer-ignoring-a-label-when-used-inside-certain-onlys).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is best achieved using HyperJumps from Link to Target.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}
\hyperlink{DEF}{\beamergotobutton{Jump to DE'Future }}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item ABC
        \item XYZ
        \item DEF
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering\hypertarget{ABC}{\label{fig:ABC}}% move the target as high as possible on page
                \caption{ABC}
               % \label{fig:ABC} % redundant
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \end{figure}
        \onslide<2>
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering\hypertarget{XYZ}{\label{fig:XYZ}}% move the target as high as possible on page
                \caption{XYZ}
                % \label{fig:XYZ} % redundant
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \end{figure}
        \onslide<3>
        \hypertarget{DEF}{ DEF Anything} you want % move the target as high as possible on page
        \hyperlink{ABC}{\beamergotobutton{Goto ABC}}
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering{\label{fig:DEF}}
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \end{figure}

    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Included here in own frame but links can be duplicated or dotted about throughout other pages
\hyperlink{ABC}{\beamergotobutton{Goto ABC}}
\hyperlink{XYZ}{\beamergotobutton{Goto XYZ}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```