# tikz-plot label and ref in beamer inside only overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, overlays, ref

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable,stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\only<1>{}
\only<2>{

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (1, 9) (2, 6) (3, 1) (4, 4)
    }; \label{important}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{important}% does NOT work
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (1, 9) (2, 6) (3, 1) (4, 4)
    }; \label{importantw}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{importantw}% working

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`\ref{importantw}` shows the symbol as expected, but `\ref{important}` does not work as it is inside `\only` (at least in my use case). How to solve this?

If I use `\onslide<2>` it messes up everything in my original work: Slide 2 appears perfect, but data of slide `2` overlaps with all other slides `1`,`3`.

Comment: in code: LaTeX Warning: Reference `important' on page 2 undefined on input line 20.

Comment: see [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in beamer page 84:

```
\label<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨label name⟩}
```

If the ⟨overlay specification⟩ is present, the label is only inserted on the specified slide. Inserting a label on
more than one slide will cause a ‘multiple labels’ warning. However, if no overlay specification is present,
the specification is automatically set to just ‘1’ and the label is thus inserted only on the first slide. This is
typically the desired behavior since it does not really matter on which slide the label is inserted, except if
you use an `\only` command and except if you wish to use that label as a hyperjump target. Then you need
to specify a slide.

Labels can be used as target of hyperjumps. A convenient way of labelling a frame is to use the `label=⟨name⟩`
option of the frame environment. However, this will cause the whole frame to be kept in memory till the
end of the compilation, which may pose a problem.

Note: `\label<2>{important}`

edit file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable,stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\only<1>{}
\only<2>{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (1, 9) (2, 6) (3, 1) (4, 4)
    }; \label<2>{important}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{important}% does NOT work
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (1, 9) (2, 6) (3, 1) (4, 4)
    }; \label{importantw}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{importantw}% working

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves the asked problem. But many plots used `\addlegendentry` for reference legend... which is not solvable using this.